# Is it possible to follow some parts of Dharmashastras, but not everything written in it?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, smriti, parashara-smriti

I was wondering whether it is possible to follow Dharmashastras partially. Is there such provision in Dharmashastras? Or do Dharmashastras categorically say that you have to follow it in its entirety?

Comment: We are already following the Dharmashastras partially. No longer we adhere to the dictate of Dharmashastras that the girl child should be married off before she undergoes menarche or pouring molten lead into the ears of Shudras who dare to hear Vaidik lore.

Comment: If you follow it partially, you'll get partial results. If you decide whether an action is dharma or adharma based on your own individual mind/heart/conscience instead of Shastras, you will be rewarded or punished based on whether your decision happened to agree with Shastras or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they do have provisions to accept only partial/logical parts and remove rest.

- A man "is said to be conversant with duty, who knows duty as
  depending on all four foundations". These four foundations of duty
  are (1) as laid down in the Vedas, (2) as laid down in the Smritis,
  (3) as sanctioned by ancient usage and customs and (4) **as approved
  by the heart or one's own conscience**.(Bhishma in MB Shanti Parva
  132)
- If a man explores, by **ratiocination**, the Vedic teaching regarding
  Dharma, he alone, and no other, understands Dharma(Manu 12.106)
- Scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the test of
  **reason**.(MB Santi CXLII)
- The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with
  reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the
  world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord
  with reason(Yoga Vasistha 2.18)
- That which has been laid down by the forefathers or decreed by a
  Ruler and is followed by a whole community of men, is the Law of Man.
  **Being man-made and imperfect, it shall be followed by the wise with wisdom and not blindly**.(Shiv Rahasya 11.2)
- One should practice what one considers to be one’s duty, **guided by
  reasons, instead of blindly following the practices of the world**.
  (MB Santi CCLXII)
- If a holy act is **against the interest of other members of the
  society, it should not be practiced**. It is Dharma which is the
  source of Artha and even of Kama. (Kurma Purana 1.2.54)
- **Let him avoid** the acquisition of wealth and the gratification of his desires, if they are opposed to the sacred law, **and even lawful
  acts which may cause pain in the future or are offensive to men**.
  (Manu Smriti 4.176)
- The Shruti, the Smriti, the conduct of good men, **what appears
  pleasant to one's own self**, and the desire which springs from a
  good resolution, are said to be the roots of Dharma. (Yajnavalkya
  1.7)
- Wealth and Pleasure, opposed to Righteousness he shall avoid; also
  such Righteousness as may be disapproved by the people.’(Viṣṇu
  71.84.85)
- He shall enjoy such pleasures as are not incompatible with
  righteousness(Āpastamba 7.20.22)
- One should **never do that to another which one regards as injurious
  to one’s own self**. This, in brief, is the rule of dharma. Other
  behavior is due to selfish desires.( Brihaspati, Mahabharata
  13.114.8)
- If the entire Dharma can be said in a few words, then it is—that
  which is unfavorable to us, do not do that to
  others.(Padmapuraana,Shrushti 19/357–358)
- One who judges pleasure or pain everywhere by the same standard as
  one applies to oneself, that yogī, O Arjuna, is regarded as the
  highest.’(Gita 6.32)

Comment: Wonderful collection!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I have taken many quotes from your answers ! @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Excellent!   Very happy that you used the quotes.

Comment: Thankyou sir ! @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: Sethu, This answer is self-contradictory. *"what appears pleasant to one's own self"* is dharma, and *"against the interest of other members of the society"* is adharma. If it appears pleasant to me to harm others, should I follow my heart, or not ? @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: @mar, the phrase 'what appears pleasant to one's own self' is coming after Sruti, Smriti and conduct of good men. So it is assumed that there is no reason for a person who knows Sruti, Smriti, and conduct of good men to find harming others pleasant.

Comment: By that logic, it is safe to assume that what is mandated in Sruti/Smriti/Conduct of Good men, can never harm others. So, following your heart/conscience is basically superseded by what is in Shastras. Otherwise a thief could give the 'conscience' logic to demand escape from punishment. Therefore, a subjective conscience may be harmful when an objective Shastra exists. @PradipGangopadhyay.

Comment: @mar, No it does not mean that. Shastra itself says that 'scripture is no scripture if it does not satisfy the test of reason'. So Sruti, Smriti, conduct of good persons must always satisfy the test of reason. All harmful elements (if they exist) of Sruti, Smriti and conduct of good men are by definition not to be followed.

Comment: You're back to same contradiction. A thief can say 'Sruti, Smriti and conduct of good men does not satisfy my test of reason - I'm simply stealing to earn a livelihood. It's no different from war. If they're powerful enough, let them protect their earnings. If they're careless enough to let me steal it, then I deserve it. So don't punish me". @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay - *"All harmful elements (if they exist)"* - If there are no harmful elements in Shastras, then there is no need for a test of reason, we can follow them blindly. If a test of reason is needed, then Shastras contain harmful elements. If Shastras contain harmful elements, then someone has to deem which elements are harmful. That person's opinion could be subjective (like a thief). Whether a thief is doing right or wrong, itself comes under question. There is no way out of this conundrum without objectively accepting Shastras are always good.

Comment: All the commentaries that you read of different shastras whether by Shankara or Ramanuja or Madhva or any other person are subjective. There is no objective interpretation of Shastras.  Every commentator considers other commentaries wrong. Shankara has written in his Gita 18.66 commentary that only that part of the Vedas are infallible that cannot be explained by reason. So the starting point of any interpretation of scripture is always reason. There is no escaping subjectivity. Just read western academic who have shown Hindu scriptures to be vile.

Comment: @mar - perhaps our Rishis wasted too much time jotting down every detail on what is dharma. They should have just said go by what is acceptable to heart. :-D

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay - if you accept everything is subjective, then why quote Acharyas at all ?

Comment: I only quote to answer any question.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay - why though ? if the law is subjective, what is the point of quoting it as an authority ? If a policeman quotes constitution, the thief can quote his conscience. The fact that constitution takes precedence over individual reason is proof enough that scriptures take precedence over one's conscience. In fact, an individual's opinion do not matter at all. The reason scriptures mention them is only as an exception - In case you don't know any sruti, smriti, conduct of good men etc, in that last resort, use your conscience. It doesn't mean use it to go against the previous ones

Answer (score 4):

Sethu Srivatsa Koduru made an almost exhaustive list in support of the view that Smritis can be followed partially. I just want to add one more verse from Yajnavalkya Smriti.

> Let him diligently follow the law (Dharma) with deed, mind and speech. But let him not follow (an ordinance) which, though lawful, is yet not conducive to heaven and is offensive to the people. **- Yajnavalkya I.156** [Yajnavalkya Smriti translated by Srisa Chandra Vidyarnava]

> One should perform religious rites carefully by deeds, mind and words; one should not perform a religious rite, which is censured by the people and which does not lead to the celestial region [even if it is sanctioned in the scriptures]. **- Yajnavalkya I.156** [Yajnavalkya Smriti translated by Manmatha Nath Dutt]

Thus, clearly, Smriti itself says that one may choose to not follow some part of it. That means it can be followed partially. And in some situations, it should be followed partially.